# A quotient of Z/25 [X]

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

In an algebra problem i may have to simplify the expression of the quotient ring :

$$(\mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z})[X] / \langle 5(X+2), 2X -22, X^2 +26 \rangle $$

I know it's easy but i just can't find it, could someone explain a simple method for it?

Comment: $2$ is a unit so $(2X-22)=(X-11)$

Comment: That's true, and $X^2 + 26 = X^2 +1$ ofc, but how would you write it with a single polynome?

Comment: Quotienting by $X-11$ means that $X=11$ in the quotient

Comment: Ok, but how can i use it?

Comment: I want to write is as $$(\mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z})[X] / <P(X)>$$ as i know the ring is principal

Comment: $(X-11,f(X))=(X-11,f(11))$ really quotienting by $X-11$ means that $X=11$

Comment: Ok thanks ill try to figure it out but  i'm still not sure

Comment: How do you know that the ring is principal? $\mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field.

Answer (score 0):

Polynomial division mod $25$ gives
$$
X^2+26 = X^2+1 = (X+11)(X-11)+122 = (X+11)(X-11)+22
$$
Therefore $22$ in the ideal. But $22$ is a unit mod $25$ and so the ideal is the whole ring.